# How to get Owner.Name?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, soql

i'm new here. I'm trying to get Owner.Name.
Using SOQL in lightning APP

```
return [Select Name, Email, Contact_level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name,  CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate From Contact];
```

In developer console I get  this, everything ok[image]

But in my APP I get this[image]

And here is console.log
[image]

JS Controller

```
ContactList : function(component, event) {
var search = component.find("searchId").get("v.value");
var action = component.get("c.getContacts");     
action.setParams({
        "search":search
    });
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

component.set('v.Contacts',response.getReturnValue());
console.log(response.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

APEX Controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getContacts(String search){ 
    string j = '%' + search + '%';
    if(search == null)
    {
    return [Select Name, Email, Contact_level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name,  CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate From Contact]; 
    }            
    return [Select Name, Email, Contact_level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name,  CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate From Contact Where name like :j]; 
}
```

Component part

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Contacts}" var="con">
<tr>
<td> {!con.Name} </td>
<td> {!con.Email} </td>
<td> {!con.Contact_level__c} </td>
<td> {!con.AccountId} </td>
<td> {!con.OwnerId} </td>
<td> {!con.CreatedById} </td>
<td> {!con.CreatedDate} </td>
```

How can I get NAMES in the APP?

Comment: Please [edit] this post to include the markup you used to try to render `Owner.Name`. That payload structure does include an `Owner` attribute which has a `Name` attribute, so it's unclear exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi, I edited the post

Comment: You're just logging it. The output sure seems to have `Owner.Name`. What's the problem?

Comment: I get IDs in my APP, and not NAMES. I need Names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `con.OwnerId` to `con.Owner.Name`.

Comment: I am so stupid. TY very much!